# [build] Error: Unable to find source space `/home/usr/Desktop/src`

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build a workspace that is stored in: `/home/usr/Desktop/ROS/workspace/`, the `workspace` directory is clean and does not contain any hidden files hence `.catkin_tools` is not present. It only contains one directory `src`. I have tried `catkin init` with empty `src` directory and by putting a package in `src`. Here is the output:

```
Catkin workspace `/home/usr/Desktop` is already initialized. No action taken.
-----------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     alternate
Extending:        [explicit] /opt/ros/melodic
Workspace:                   /home/usr/Desktop
-----------------------------------------------------------
Build Space:       [missing] /home/usr/Desktop/build
Devel Space:       [missing] /home/usr/Desktop/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /home/usr/Desktop/install
Log Space:         [missing] /home/usr/Desktop/logs
Source Space:      [missing] /home/usr/Desktop/src
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
-----------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None
-----------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       None
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
-----------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
-----------------------------------------------------------


-----------------------------------------------------------
WARNING: Source space `/home/usr/Desktop/src` does
not yet exist.
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

What I don't understand is why is catkin looking for workspace in `/home/usr/Desktop` and not the `current directory`? The same package is easily built with `catkin_make though` and I am able to run all the nodes. Also If I put `src` in `/home/usr/Desktop` I am able to build successfully.

I am using ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04. I am not sure about the catkin tools version but i installed it from here: https://jbohren-ct.readthedocs.io/en/pre-0.4.0-docs/installing.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335290/%5Bbuild%5D-error:-unable-to-find-source-space-%60/home/usr/desktop/src%60/) by [khansaadbinhasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33367/khansaadbinhasan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2019-10-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-13**:\

> I am not sure about the catkin tools version but i installed it from here: https://jbohren-ct.readthedocs.io/en/pre-0.4.0-docs/installing.html

Please try to always use the main documentation when using any tools. In this case that would be here:

```
https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
```

The fact that the link you posted (eventually) leads to an account called: `jbohren-forks` seems to suggest it is not the main version of the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> the `workspace` directory is clean and does not contain any hidden files hence `.catkin_tools` is not present.

No, but:

> ```
> Workspace:                   /home/usr/Desktop
> ```

it's likely there is a `.catkin_tools` directory in `/home/usr/Desktop`.

What is the output of `ls -al $HOME/Desktop/.catkin_tools`?

The rest of the warnings/errors you are getting follow from this. If `$HOME/Desktop` is the workspace according to `catkin_tools`, there is no `src` space (as that would be in `$HOME/Desktop/workspace/src`).

---

Edit:

> I didn't knew i had it on my desktop, but why should that matter? I can have multiple workspaces, what if desktop is a workspace, I cannot have any other workspace inside it?

Having multiple workspaces is completely supported. But you just can't *nest workspaces* (ie: workspaces inside other workspaces).

If you want to have multiple workspaces, make them siblings or place them in entirely different directories.

It might also be informative to take a look at [wiki/catkin/workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces). Specifically: workspace overlaying.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khansaadbinhasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33367/khansaadbinhasan/) on 2019-10-13**:
Thanks for the answer. It worked, I didn't knew i had it on my desktop, but why should that matter? I can have multiple workspaces, what if desktop is a workspace, I cannot have any other workspace inside it?

**Comment by [Thimaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63262/thimaya/) on 2020-11-13**:
Hello so i am a beginner and have a similar issue, how exactly did u work around it?

catkin build returns an error saying source at `home/thimaya/src` doesnt exist
while im in `~/ws_moveit/` .

My home directory contains `catkin_ws`  , `ws_moveit`  and `.catkin_tools` .

I probbed into profiles in `.catkin_tools` and it said  `source : src`

is it not possible to make a the folder in the home directory cuz of catkin_ws ? I tried making one in another partition of mine but i had the same error.

Thanks in advance !

**Comment by [khansaadbinhasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33367/khansaadbinhasan/) on 2020-11-13**:
@thimaya It has been a long time since I asked that question. From what I remember, I had made my desktop into a workspace and then deleted all files except the hidden `.catkin_tools`. When I tried to `build` my workspace nested inside Desktop it gave error.

You should not make your `Home` into a workspace. What you should do. Press `Ctrl+H` delete `.catkin_tools`. Also delete other files and folders created by ROS.

Now make one folder say `catkin_ws` then follow tutorials to build this workspace and create packages. Also, whenever you run `build` or `make`, make sure you are in `catkin_ws` folder.